# Google Recaptcha V3 Implementation in Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I have requirement to add Recaptcha in Lightning Web Component component. I have used V3 of google recaptacha. I have added https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js url in static resource and referenced in LWC component.

**On running this is showing**

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/v1550471573786/recaptcha__en.js' from origin 'https://******--*****--livepreview.cs77.force.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

I have added url in CORS,CSP sites and Remote site setting. Can any one help in this issue.

Comment: I suspect it cannot due to similar security issue as with AURA components - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/151726/is-it-possible-to-have-google-recaptcha-in-a-custom-lightning-component


Here is how to do it within the Aura component via VisualForce
http://varasi.com/salesforce/embedding-google-recaptcha-v2-in-salesforce-lightning-component-to-increase-security/

Comment: Yes, We have implemented by Aura+VF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a solution that you can try.

Upload a static resource: **recaptcha2.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>reCAPTCHA demo: Simple page</title>
     <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="?" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="POST">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdIAZgUAAAAAFX4gX_8CQrVXT-5kPka0w_i2bnY"></div>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validateForm(){

            if(grecaptcha.getResponse().length == 0){
                alert('Please click the reCAPTCHA checkbox');
                parent.postMessage("captcha failed", location.origin);
                return false;
            }
            parent.postMessage("captcha success", location.origin);
            return true;
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You will need to create a resource file called: **recaptcha2.resource-meta.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StaticResource xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <cacheControl>Private</cacheControl>
    <contentType>text/html</contentType>
</StaticResource>
```

Make an LWC component: captcha.html

```
<template>
    <iframe src={navigateTo} name="captchaFrame" onload={captchaLoaded} width="350" height="500" style="border:1px solid red"></iframe>
</template>
```

and the JavaScript: captcha.js

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import pageUrl from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/recaptcha2';

export default class GoogleCapatcha extends LightningElement {
    @track navigateTo;
    captchaWindow = null;

    constructor(){
        super();

        this.navigateTo = pageUrl;

        window.addEventListener("message", this.listenForMessage);
    }

    captchaLoaded(evt){
        var e = evt;
        console.log(e.target.getAttribute('src') + ' loaded');
        if(e.target.getAttribute('src') == pageUrl){
            // You know that your captcha is loaded
        } 
    }

    listenForMessage(message){
        console.log(message);
    }
}
```

I hadn't used a captcha prior, when registering the domain I didn't realize that I should leave off the https://.

Comment: How are you checking that captcha is verified? It is similar to VF page addition in LWC component.

Comment: Do you mean, how would I notify the parent component that the form submission was successful?

Comment: Yes. How to check that captcha is verified? Because in LWC window.addEventListener will create problem. we can't raise event from this function.

Comment: You can use postMessage to send an event to the parent window. Let me update the Answer. Although this is now a different question :)

Comment: @Dhanik Lal Sahni did this answer your question?

Comment: I tried the above solution and it worked well except I am trying to send an event from listenForMessage to the parent component. Its getting dispatched but it is not receiving in the parent, Any idea?

Comment: Where are you sending the event from? From the GoogleCaptcha component? Depending on if you are trying to bubble the event up you will need to follow different patterns: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events

Comment: @KevinHill, can you please let me know how to view the output of this lwc?
I cannot able to see this under custom section in app builder

Comment: This solution isn't complete. The response you're getting from grecaptcha.getResponse() is just the token. You still need to verify that token with the server (an Apex controller) against the secret key. Otherwise all you're doing here is allowing the form to submit just when you get a token which can be easily scraped and isn't secure.

Answer (score 5):

Not to self promote, but I would like to share some new solutions to consider that don't require a VisualForce iframe in this just published blog post: https://www.learncommunitycloud.com/s/article/Implementing-reCAPTCHA-in-Community-Cloud

For v3, you can leverage JavaScript Events and Lightning Community [head markup](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_page_head.htm) such as:

```
<!--reCaptcha v3-->
<script>
    document.addEventListener('grecaptchaExecute', function(e) {
        grecaptcha.execute('reCAPTCHA_site_key', {action: e.detail.action}).then(function(token) {
            document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('grecaptchaVerified', {'detail': {response: token, action:e.detail.action}}));
        });
    }); 
</script>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=reCAPTCHA_site_key'></script>
```

*Replace reCAPTCHA_site_key with your v3 site key in 2 places in the example above

Comment: I tried following the article but it is not working, I have used the code for v2 checkbox but reCaptcha is not visible

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that followed the instructions above but got the "invalid domain for site key " error, make sure you add "https://www.google.com" to remote site settings.

Also, your static resource 's cache control should be public as well.