# Lightning Web Component - Google Recaptcha

Tags: lightning-web-components

How do I include Google recaptcha in LWC ? I am brand new to Salesforce development.

Comment: you can have look here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252419/google-recaptcha-v3-implementation-in-lightning-web-component