# Google Recaptcha integration in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, google

I am referring to [Google Recaptcha V3 Implementation in Lightning Web Component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252419/google-recaptcha-v3-implementation-in-lightning-web-component/303626#303626)

In the solution for the above link what is the the use of recaptcha2.resource-meta.xml and how to create it. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of just putting a link, do you mind quoting the specific parts of that source in the question? If the link URL changes, your question won't have any relevance in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .resource-meta.xml file tells Salesforce details about the Static Resource file, such as the Content-Type and the Cache-Control setting. Lots of components (e.g. a Visualforce Page) have associated metadata, and a meta.xml file desecribes those additional properties. The .resource file itself contains the contents of the static resource file (the file to be uploaded).