# Community reCaptcha - Lightning component

Tags: community, lightning-components, recaptcha

I've saw some links but apparently all of them are outdated.

I'm trying to add the recaptcha on a community that only contains a custom lightning component.

I've tried to follow this tutorial and no success. https://www.pwc.pt/pt/servicos/advisory/customer-transformation/artigos/google-recaptcha-salesforce.html

This is showing below image only:
[image]

Also I've tried to follow SF guides and documentation (which are incomplete) as well. So I wonder if anyone has a newer version of it.

Here is the iframe that Ive used on the component:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false">

<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit' />  
<div id="widgetId1" class="g-recaptcha" style="transform: scale(0.74);transform-origin: 0 0;-webkit-transform:scale(0.74);-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0"></div>

<style>
    body, div{
        background:transparent !important;
    }
</style>  

<script type="text/javascript">
    var onloadCallback = function() {
        console.log('onloadCallback');
        grecaptcha.render('widgetId1', {
            'sitekey' : '6LfBMvgdAAAAACTLeD-9UDN8RaZ-zP4RTWOxpzgS',
            'data-size' : 'compact',
            'data-theme' : 'light'
        });
    };
console.log("event.originsadsd vf");
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    var hostURL = 'letsgetcheckedus--awsdev.lightning.force.com';
    console.log("event.origin vf");
    console.log(event);
    console.log(event.origin);
    if(event.origin !== hostURL){
        return;
    }
   
    if(event.data.action == "alohaCallingCAPTCHA"){
       
        var message = document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").value;
        if (message == ""){
            parent.postMessage({ action: "alohaCallingCAPTCHA", alohaResponseCAPTCHA : "NOK" }, hostURL);
        }
        else{
            parent.postMessage({ action: "alohaCallingCAPTCHA", alohaResponseCAPTCHA : "OK" },  hostURL);
        }
    }
}, false);      

</script>


</apex:page>
```

Here is the security settings on the community:
[image]

And here is the error getting:
[image]

Comment: What's the specific issue that you are facing from that tutorial? Is the iframe not rendering? Is the event not bubbling correctly? Some specific error message? I also notice this is Captcha V2 in the tutorial, this Q&A has an example of V3: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252419/google-recaptcha-v3-implementation-in-lightning-web-component

Comment: hi there, I've just edited the question showing what's happening by following that tutorial

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's a little hard to try and help diagnose.  You may think you have the same code as what's in the linked tutorial, but you could be missing something.

Comment: just edited it @VictorLockwood

Comment: This is better, but can you show more of what's in the component itself?

Comment: @VictorLockwood the component itself is not relevant, lets say that the component is just an example to use the recaptcha. The relevant info here is that I want to use that on an aura component that is being shown on a public community page

Comment: Now that you've added the relevant errors in your post I'm inclined to agree.